# Experience of moving to 64 bit JVM

Tags: java, 64-bit, jvm

Our company is planning to move to 64 bit JVM in order to get away from 2 GB maximum heap size limit. Google gave me very mixed results about 64 bit JVM performance.
Has anyone tried moving to 64 bit java and share your experience

Comment: x64 or non-x64? For the most part it just increases the memory usage and hence memory bandwidth. For x86, AMD created a less insane instruction set than x86.

Comment: @Anders, not everyone is so obsessed with those numbers as you! :P Some people (can you imagine?) answer just to help.

Comment: @Vladimir Dyuzhev:  Obsessed is not the issue.  It's the way the community works.  Answer and accept are how one determines who has a history of good answers.  No accept means no history of good answers.  Without the history of good answers, it's hard to know how much trust to put in an answer.

Comment: @Vladimir, stackoverflow works best if the original poster points out which answer is the best FOR HIM/HER.

Comment: Sorry guys.. I agree its may mistake. I learn from answers but forgot to accept them.. Will do it from now on.

Comment: @Fazal: You can do that from now in the past, for **all** 7 of your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the larger heap, then questions of performance are rather moot, aren't they? Or do you have a plan for horizontal scaling?

The main problem that I've heard with 64-bit apps is that a full garbage collection can take a very long time (because it's based on number of live objects). So you want to carefully tune the GC parameters to avoid full collections (I've heard one anecdote about a company that had 64 Gb of heap, and tuned their GC so that they'd never to a full GC; they'd simply shut down once a week).

Other than that, recognize that Java is 32-bit by design, so you're not likely to see any huge performance increase from moving data 64 bits at a time. And you're still limited to 32-bit array indices.

Comment: We have a JVM where the gc runs in parallel which works well, but if the gc isn't done when the next gc is to be started, the JVM halts until the second gc is done.  Bad!  Happens a bit as the OS is very aggressive about swapping memory out.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by Java is 32-bit by design? from what I know, Java is platform independent by design no?

Comment: The remark about 32 bit by design is odd. When we discuss 32/64/128 bit it is usually about the size of a pointer, which affects the size of working memory. The fact that Java uses ints for arrays limits the size of a single array but an abstraction like nio buffers can be used to efficiently work around this. Since this is not perfect, there are plans to allow indexes to be longs. However, it is not a limitation in a technical way like a max heap of 4Gb.

Answer (score 9):

**In a nutshell:** 64-bit JVMs will consume more memory for object references and a few other types (generally not significant), consume more memory per thread (often significant on high-volume sites) and enable you to have larger heaps (generally only important if you have many long-lived objects)

**Longer Answers/Comments:**

- The comment that Java is 32-bit by
  design is misleading. Java
  memory-addressing is either 32, or
  64-bit, but the VM spec ensures that
  most fields (e.g. int, long, double,
  etc.) are the same regardless.
- Also - the GC tuning comments while
  pertinent for number of objects, may
  not be relevant, GC can be quick on
  JVMs with large heaps (I've worked
  with heaps up to 15GB, with very
  quick GC) - it depends more on how
  you play with the generational
  collector schemes, and what your
  object usage pattern is. While in the
  past people have spent lots of energy
  tuning parameters, it's very workload
  dependent, and modern (Java 5+) JVMs
  are very good at self-tuning - unless
  you have lots of data you're more
  likely to harm yourself than help
  with aggresive JVM tuning.
- As mentioned on x86 architectures,
  the 64-bit EMT64 or x64 processors
  also include new instructions for
  doing things like atomic writes, or
  other options which may also impact
  high-performance applications.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "fields (e.g. int, long, double, etc.) are the same regardless" ?

Answer (score 3):

Works fine for us. Why don't you simply try setting it up and run your load test suite under a profiler like jvisualvm?

Answer (score 1):

We've written directly to 64bit and I can see no adverse behavior...

Answer (score 1):

Naively taking 32 bit JVM workloads and putting them on 64 bit produces a performance and space hit in my experience.

However, Most of the major JVM vendors have now implemented a good technology that essentially compresses some of the heap - it's called compressed references or compressed oops for 64 bit JVMs that aren't "big" (ie: in the 4-30gb range).

This makes a big difference and should make a 32->64 transition much lower impact.

Reference for the IBM JVM:  [link text](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.user.aix64.60/user/garbage_compressed_refs.html)

Comment: I think this is -XX:+UseCompressedOops for the oracle jvm